# Access kubernetes secure API after running with docker

Tags: kubernetes

I've created a kubenetes cluster on my Mac with docker-machine, following the documentation here:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/

I can access the normal api from inside the instance on 127.0.0.1:8080, but I want to access it externally from my macbook.  I know there is a secure port :6443, but I'm unsure how to set up the credentials to access this port.

There are lots of instructions on how to do it on custom installs of kubernetes, but I don't know how to do it inside the docker containers I'm running.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, you will want to use Virtual Box's [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) capabilities. An example from the documentation:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "MyVM" --natpf1 "k8srule,tcp,,6443,,6443"
```

This forwards port 6443 on all hosts interfaces to port 6443 of the guest. Port forwarding can also be configured through the VirtualBox UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's like a workaround but most of the time, I think KubeOnDocker setup is for developper that don't need the credentials mecanism :

When you start the KubeOnDocker, `--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests` point to [master.json](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master.json). If you look the apiserver start command, you will see that `--insecure-bind-address` is 127.0.0.1. If you use `--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi` it will point to [master-multi.json](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master-multi.json), `--insecure-bind-address` will be `0.0.0.0` and the apiserver will be accessible from everywhere.

Note that you will need to start etcd with manifests-multi.

```
# Not tested start
docker run \
  -d \
  --net=host \
  gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.2.1 \
    /usr/local/bin/etcd \
    --listen-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:4001 \
    --advertise-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:4001 \
    --data-dir=/var/etcd/data
```